# How to integrate Craft Commerce with Salesforce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, integration

We're looking for a way to integrate Craft Commerce with Salesforce. What are the options there?

Is there a Craft API to talk to? (I can't seem to be able to find it...)

And the other option is to write a plugin in Craft that communicates outwards to Salesforce, I suppose?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a Craft API to talk to?

Yes, but it depends on what sort of API you're talking about and you'll need a [Craft](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/introduction) [plugin](https://pluginfactory.io) no matter what.

At the PHP level, Craft has a [service layer API](https://craftcms.com/classreference#craft.app.services) that plugins can utilize.

If you're looking for a web service API where you can configure what gets exposed so that 3rd party apps can consume Craft data, there is the [Element API](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api) plugin that works with any Craft elements (including plugin elements, like Orders, Products and Variants like in Commerce).  Note that this is read-only and is not a REST API.

There currently isn't a native REST API in Craft, but feel free to add your comments to [this feature request](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/815).  It's also possible for a plugin to implement its own REST API using its own controller endpoints and authentication/authorization methods.

As far as consuming 3rd party web endpoints, Craft ships with Guzzle that a plugin can utilize, or it can use any other library it desires (or straight up cURL).